# не могу разобраться с кодировками при выводе результата работы процесса (команда tasklist)

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode

Прошу помочь с такой проблемой:
Пытаюсь посчитать количество памяти суммарно для всех приложений. В коде не стал суммировать пока, просто пытаюсь вывести данные в int, но при выполнении int(i[-13:-3]) получаю исключение ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '   74\xa0420 ', понимаю, что, скорее всего, проблема с кодировками, но как решить не понимаю..подскажите, пожалуйста. Также в качестве эксперимента, пытался добавить срез i[-13:-3] в список в цикле с readlines(), получаю примерно такой результат ['        8 ', '      136 ', '   74\xa0408 ', '    1\xa0088 ', '    4\xa0976 ' и так далее, там куча всего.

```
    import os
    import subprocess

    def get_inf():
        p = subprocess.Popen('tasklist', shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
        output = p.stdout.read().decode('cp866')
        f = open('Buffer.txt', 'w')
        f.write(output)
        f.close()
        f = open('Buffer.txt', 'r')
        for i in f.readlines():
            if i.rstrip().endswith('КБ'):
                print(int(i[-13:-3]))
        f.close()

    def main():
        get_inf()
```

Answer (score 3):

`\xa0` это *non-breaking space*, который выглядит в точности как пробел. Можно его просто убрать из строки перед преобразованием в `int`:

```
print(int(i[-13:-3].replace('\xa0', '')))
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно убрать все "не цифры" из строки перед преобразованием строки в число:

```
def to_int(num_str):
    return int("".join([c for c in num_str if c.isdigit()])

print(to_int(i[-13:-3))
```

Comment: Тогда уж `filter(str.isdigit, num_str)` красивше будет вместо спискового сокращения )

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, наверное `"".join(filter(str.isdigit, num_str))` - будет выглядеть лучше)

Comment: Не люблю просто "пустые" списковые сокращения по типу `x for x in arr`, это всегда признак того, что тут нужен либо `filter` либо `map`